# Accessing Microsoft.Office dlls (PowerPoint) without Office installed?

Tags: interop, powerpoint

I am showing a PowerPoint presentation in a WPF application by using Windows functions SetParent() and SetWindowPos() of user32.dll and set the handle to my application handle.

I've referenced Microsoft.Office.Core.dll and Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll in my project for opening the Presentation and sliding back and forth like this:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
Application pp = new Application();
Presentation p = pp.Presentations.Open(...);
```

Everything works fine when PowerPoint is installed.

When its not installed I get the error: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {...} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered"

I thought it might work if only the free PowerPoint Viewer is installed, but that seems not to be enough.

Is there a possibility to work without full licensed version of PowerPoint or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  As I understand it, the interops are more or less the same thing as type libraries in earlier com-based languages.  They list the capabilities of e.g. PowerPoint and tell the host language how to access these capabilities.  They are not the actual capabilities.

Having the interops/TLBs is equivalent to having the driver's manual for a car.  You can read it to learn about the car's features, but until you HAVE the car, you can't DRIVE the car.

And until you HAVE PowerPoint, you can't drive it either.